# One row class have many col classes

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

is this right to have on row class

```
<div class='row'>
  <div class='col-lg-4'></div>
  <div class='col-lg-4'></div>
  <div class='col-lg-4'></div>

  <div class='col-lg-4'></div>
  <div class='col-lg-4'></div>
  <div class='col-lg-4'></div>
</div>
```

or I must keep each 12 columns in different div with row class?

Comment: depends on what you are doing. you can have as many divs in a div as you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's perfectly fine to have more than a total of 12 columns' worth of width in a single *row* div; in fact, it's a part of how Bootstrap is supposed to work.

When your example of divs with 3x 4 large columns is loaded on a screen of size 'medium' or smaller, they'll be treated as a full 12 columns. The nature of this behavior is called column wrapping. You can add another div of class *row* if you like, but you're doing nothing wrong.

For more on column wrapping, here's the relevant section from Bootstrap's docs:
http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-example-wrapping

Answer (score 1):

You can certainly embed divs within each other with different classes.   When formatting with CSS, you will just need to pay attention to the inheritance rules.

In other words, this is fine.